# ASP.Net MVC4 self-hosted API on same port as website

Tags: asp.net, ajax, upload, asp.net-web-api

Dear developer friends,

I have developed a self-hosted API in ASP.Net MVC4 (e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx), because I needed a solution where I could upload super large files. This works smoothly.

Now I want to upload files to my newly written API through the [Bluimp JQuery Upload component](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

This works fine, except for some small flaws:
- the progress-bar is not showing
- JQuery raises an error: *Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL...*

It seems clear that this error is raised, because my API runs on another port than the web application, and ajax calls cannot be made over cross domains / ports.

I have already added the forceIframeTransport: true parameter to the fileupload component call. This does some good - without it I cannot upload files at all (because the component tries to upload with an ajax call).

So.. I figured that if there's some way to run my self hosted API on the same port as my web-application (with explicitly defined routes), my world will be happy and shiny again. However.. I'm not quite sure whether this is possible at all..

Unfortunately a proxy from my ASP.Net application will not help me here, as I wrote the API to *avoid* the IIS limitations (regarding maximum upload size). Using my self hosted API as proxy might to the job, but I think this is a bit.. overkill?

Anyone? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! Solved it!

var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:49302/**api**");

In other words - the web api ONLY works when the url starts with **/api**. All other requests are picked up by my MVC4 web application. But they run on the same port.

So to answer my question: yes it's possible. Just add a root directory.

Comment: Incredible. I have solved the biggest problem since the existence of mankind, and NO ONE here acknowledges it!